# Is NSLog meant as a general purpose write?

Tags: objective-c

In objective-c when I create a new project I get this in the main:

```
NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
```

I cannot find any other easy writing methods in the Foundation library.
Is `NSLog` the `printf` of objective-c? is it recommended to use it in production for printing on screen (of command line tools)?
If not, how can I print to screen using the Foundation library?

Edit:
It looks like `NSLog` also adds timestamp and things, I thought thats only the Xcode console.
How can I print objective c objects using a format like `NSLog` without timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like, you can do what I usually do: define my own printing function that works just as well, minus the timestamp:

```
void IFPrint (NSString *format, ...) {
    if (!format) return;
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, format);
    fputs([[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:arguments] autorelease] UTF8String], stdout); // Omit autorelease call if using ARC.
    va_end(arguments);
}
```

The way this works is that it uses `NSString`'s text parsing (exactly how you use `%@` to print objects via `NSLog`), and prints it out very simply to the screen. It's faster than `NSLog`, and doesn't go through the system log service.

Comment: I think in the next to last line, you meant `fputs([output UTF8String], stout);`. I edited the snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Objective C is a superset of C, so you can still use your `printf`, `scanf`, etc.  `NSLog` prints timestamp and some process information, and shows up in the system Console.  `NSLog` also knows how to print Obj-C objects (use the `%@` format specifier).

Answer (score 0):

You can use printf.  `NSLog` is convenient if you are printing `NSStrings` and other Objective-C objects.

Comment: And what if I want to write NSStrings and other objective-c objects without timestamp?

Comment: Use the `description` method on the object to get the debug string, then call one of the methods to turn the NSString into a C string, like `printf("%s", [[obj description] UTF8String])`

Answer (score 0):

NSLog is intended for writing debug trace to the console.  Objective-c is not really geared towards developing a console based application, so if that was what you were intending, I would either look at the underlying C libraries and use `printf` and `scanf`, or a framework like this:

[Objective-C Command Line Framework](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2008/04/29/ddcli/)

In terms of how you can print out the object's description without the NSLog's timestamp information, I would use printf to print the output of `[[myObject description] UTF8String]`, as I presume that's what NSLog uses when you print out the object using the %@ format specifier.

Comment: `-description` returns an `NSString *` so be sure to ask it for its utf-8 representation before using `%s` with `printf`.

Comment: @Richard - I tried to carefully choose my words - I didn't say you couldn't or I wouldn't - I said 'not geared'.  The standard libraries (not talking about the c libraries) provided with the language doesn't appear to have a bunch of objective-c classes to handle std-in and std-out.  That's fine, and I would use the underlying C to do that.

Comment: I haven't needed to use them, but `NSInputStream`, `NSOutputStream`, and `NSFileHandle` seem like they'd do the job.